# Display No Reviews message when there are no reviews in angular

Tags: angular

I just to display No Reviews message for the user who don't have any reviews. Currently when the Review button is pressed, it shows the reviews for the user who have the reviews, but if any user who don't have any review, Review Button pressing show nothing.

Here is the code

```
<div class="checkbox-item mt-2"  (click)="getReviews(item.offer_by.id)">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" >Reviews</button>
</div>

<div class="çontainer" *ngFor="let items of reviews" >
   <div class="row" *ngIf="items.tasker_id == item.offer_by.id">
      <h6>{{items.name}}</h6>
      <div class="emVaRl">
          <div class="lnfldP">
          <svg width="16" height="16" class="elJCm" viewBox="0 0 24 24"  *ngFor='let in of 
          counter(items.review_rating) ;let i = index'>
          <path d="M16.2 8.16l4.74.73a1.23 1.23 0 01.67 2.11l-3.46 3.28a1.23 1.23 0 00-.37 1.1l.77 4.68a1.24 1.24 0 01-1.82 1.29L12.5 19.1a1.28 1.28 0 00-1.16 0l-4.27 2.17A1.25 1.25 0 015.27 20l.85-4.68a1.19 1.19 0 00-.34-1.09l-3.41-3.4a1.23 1.23 0 01.71-2.1l4.75-.64a1.26 1.26 0 00.95-.67l2.16-4.24a1.25 1.25 0 012.24 0l2.09 4.28a1.22 1.22 0 00.93.7z">
          </path>
          </svg>
       </div>
    </div>

           <p>({{items.review}})</p>
        <hr>
     </div>
</div>
```

.ts code

```
review(data: any): boolean {
    data['job_id'] = this.jobOffer.id;
    data['tasker_id'] = this.jobOffer.assign_to_id;
    this.ds.addReview(data).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.status == true) {
        this.makeReview = false;
        window.location.reload();
        this.ts.success(resp.msg);
        return true;
      } else {
        this.ts.error(resp.msg);
        return false;
      }
    });
    return true;
  }


getReviews(data: any) {
    
    this.ds.getReviews(data).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.status == true) {
        this.reviews = [];
        this.rating = '';
        this.total_rating = '';
        this.reviews = resp.data;
        this.rating = resp.rating;
        this.total_rating = resp.total_rating;
        return true;
      } 
    }, );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this and show your .ts code also

```
<div *ngIf="reviews">
  <div *ngIf="reviews.length > 0">
      <div class="çontainer" *ngFor="let items of reviews">
         <div class="row" *ngIf="items.tasker_id == item.offer_by.id">
             <h6>{{items.name}}</h6>
                <div class="emVaRl">
                  <div class="lnfldP">
                    <svg width="16" height="16" class="elJCm" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      *ngFor='let in of counter(items.review_rating) ;let i =index'>
                      <path
                        d="M16.2 8.16l4.74.73a1.23 1.23 0 01.67 2.11l-3.46 3.28a1.23 1.23 0 00-.37 1.1l.77 4.68a1.24 1.24 0 01-1.82 1.29L12.5 19.1a1.28 1.28 0 00-1.16 0l-4.27 2.17A1.25 1.25 0 015.27 20l.85-4.68a1.19 1.19 0 00-.34-1.09l-3.41-3.4a1.23 1.23 0 01.71-2.1l4.75-.64a1.26 1.26 0 00.95-.67l2.16-4.24a1.25 1.25 0 012.24 0l2.09 4.28a1.22 1.22 0 00.93.7z">
                      </path>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>({{items.review}})</p>
                <hr>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="reviews.length == 0">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">No Reviews</h3>
          </div>
```

edit your .ts code like this

```
getReviews(data: any) {
    
    this.ds.getReviews(data).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.status == true) {
        this.reviews = [];
        this.rating = '';
        this.total_rating = '';
        this.reviews = resp.data;
        this.rating = resp.rating;
        this.total_rating = resp.total_rating;
        return true;
      } else {
        this.ts.warning('No Reviews')
        this.ts.error(resp.msg);
        return false;
      }
    }, (error : any) => {
      this.ts.warning('No Reviews')
    });
  }
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Got your idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="reviews?.length > 0; else noReview">
  <div class="container" *ngFor="let items of reviews">
  [...]
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noReview>
  <p>Sorry there is no review yet...</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I have tried this. For the user who don't have reviews shows correct message "Sorry there us no review yet". But there are others users who have reviews as well and this code isn't showing their details. Image is here https://freeimage.host/i/pc0OG4

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there are reviews in the container div and iterate the iterate the reviews using a ng-container.

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="reviews.length > 0">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let items of reviews">
      ...
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Edit:
Invert div and ng-container, otherwise there would be multiple reviews inside a single container.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="reviews.length > 0">
   <div class="container" *ngFor="let items of reviews">
      ...
   </div>
</ng-container>
```